# Swift: How can I change the size of Thumb Image on UISlider based of the value of the slider?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I haven't found an answer for this in Swift.

I have a UISlider that changes the value of a brush size for a drawing app I'm making. I want the size of the thumb image to update depending on the value of the slider's thumb position.

Here's a screenshot of the slider for some context:
[image]

I set the initial image of the thumb in viewDidLoad()

```
self.brushSizeSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "black"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

and have an IBAction for the slider as follows:

```
    @IBAction func brushSizeSliderChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    if sender == brushSizeSlider {
        self.brushWidth = CGFloat(sender.value)
        println("the size of the brush is: \(self.brushWidth)")
    }
}
```

What should I add to `brushSizeSliderChanged` to change the size of it's thumb image depending on the value of brushSizeSliders thumb position / value?

Comment: You have to update the slider's thumb image with an appropriately sized image.

Comment: How what? Are you asking how to generate an image of the appropriate size?

Comment: How would I generate an image of the appropriate size? Appropriate size being the value of the slider.

Comment: As rmaddy says, you would have to constantly create a new thumb image and install it in the slider as it draws. That would be a lot of overhead, and might be too slow to keep up. I'd be tempted to create my own custom control that acts like a slider but draws the thumb using a CAShapeLayer. Sliders are not that complex.

Comment: There is a (recent) answer on how to subclass the slider in order to make a custom slider bar. Cant recall the exact thread.

Comment: Custom slider bar or custom thumb image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var ratio : CGFloat = CGFloat ( sender.value + 0.5)
var thumbImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: "yourImage")!
var size = CGSizeMake( thumbImage.size.width * ratio, thumbImage.size.height * ratio )
self.setThumbImage( self.imageWithImage(thumbImage, scaledToSize: size), forState: UIControlState.Normal )
```

Add this code to your action method

Comment: func imageWithImage(image:UIImage, scaledToSize newSize:CGSize) -> UIImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0);
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a more recent API**

```
extension UIImage {

/// Непропорциональное масштабирование к указанному размеру
/// - Parameter size: конечный размер изображения
/// - Parameter displayScale: масштаб, в котором создаётся итоговое изображение
/// - Returns: изображение необходимого размера
func scaled(to size: CGSize, scale displayScale: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.scale) -> UIImage {
    let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.preferred()
    format.scale = displayScale
    return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: format).image { _ in
        draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    }
}
```